# Difficulty in installing rasterio

Tags: python, windows

I need to clip a raster file using a shape file. I know the code of doing that using rasterio. But I cannot install rasterio.

I tried:

```
conda install rasterio gdal=2 -y
```

but it shows installing since 3 hours.

is there any other package that can be used for the same purpose?

Comment: Are you sure that version number is correct? The [latest version of rasterio](https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/) specifies 3.1

Comment: I tried pip install rasterio. it does not work. I have solved the problem by creating new env. Here is a useful video for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-JD-VL3I2M